# detect changes in vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I would like to find the first element of a series of equal elements in a vector.
For example I have

```
V = [1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 2 2 3 3 4 4]
```

my result should be

```
R = [1 2 3 4 2 3 4]
```

Unfortunately I can't use `unique` because it would give me

```
R = [1 2 3 4];
```

Thanks

Comment: I have added a solution for the more general case where your vector may contain infinite values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for this particular case:

```
 R=V(find(diff([-Inf V])));
```

Same as

```
 R=V(abs(diff([-Inf V]))>0);
```

(and the last one, as noted by Praetorian, can be expressed *much* more tidily as

```
 R=V(diff([-Inf V])~=0);
```

saving you use of `abs`

Finally, if you want to be very logical,

```
 R=V(~~diff([-Inf V]));
```

also works

Comment: Or use logical indexing: `R = V(diff([-Inf V]) ~= 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
R=V([logical(diff(V)), true]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Generalized solution**

If your vector may contain Infinite values, here is how you can deal with it if you consider infinite values as their stored value:

```
 V = [-Inf Inf Inf 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 2 2 3 3 4 4 Inf -Inf -Inf Inf];

 idx = [true ~isnan(diff(V))];
 R = V(idx);
 R([true logical(diff(R))])
```

The result will be:

```
 -Inf   Inf     1     2     3     4     2     3     4   Inf  -Inf   Inf
```

Of course this will also work for the simple case.

In general your vector may also contain `NaN` values,  in this case I would recommend another preparation step in order to remove this using `isnan`.

---

**Original answer**

Another simple solution for the same basic problem: rather than keeping what you need, delete what you don't need.

```
R = V;
R(~diff([-Inf R]))=[];
```

If you just want to 'clean up' your variable, you will only need one line.

In case performance is an issue I would bet on one of the other solutions (without `find`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it fairly crudely like this:

```
V = [ 1   2   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   2   2   3   3   4   4 ];
W = [-Inf V(1:size(V)(2)-1)];
X = V - W;
Y = find(X);
Z = V(Y);
```

but I think @Try Hard's answer is probably more elegant.